# Gettext no realiza las traducciones en web PHP con el servidor Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, debian

Desde ya muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Mi sistema es un Debian Jessy sobre una arquitectura **armv7l**. Con servidor Nginx y PHP 5.6

Problema: quiero realizar la traducción de mi aplicación web realizada en PHP con Gettext y no consigo que realice la traducción. *Peeeero este mismo código **sí** funciona correctamente sobre el servidor Apache*.

Mi proyecto tiene la siguiento estructura:

```
TESTGETTEXT (nombre del proyecto)
- Locale
    - en_GB
        LC_MESSAGES
           en_GB.mo
           en_GB.po
    - es_ES
        LC_MESSAGES
           es_ES.mo
           es_ES.po
- index.php
```

El contenido de mi index.php es el siguiente:

```
<?php

session_start();
$language = "es_ES";

if (isset($_GET['language']))
{
    $language = $_GET['language'];
}

putenv("LANG=" . $language);
putenv("LC_ALL={$language}");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

$domain = $language;
bindtextdomain($domain, "./Locale/");
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

if (function_exists("gettext"))
{
    echo _("La función gettext existe");
}
else
{
    echo _("La función gettext no existe");
}


echo '<br>' . $language . '<br>';
echo _("Hola mundo");

?>
```

El contenido de mi archivo `en_GB.po` es el siguiente:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: test\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2017-08-31 10:38+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2017-08-31 10:39+0100\n"
"Last-Translator: Jonathan López <j.lopez@test.es>\n"
"Language-Team: jlu <j.lopez@test.es>\n"
"Language: en_GB\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.5.4\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _;gettext;gettext_noop\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: /home/jonathan/www/testGettext\n"

#: /home/jonathan/www/testGettext/index.php:22
msgid "La función gettext existe"
msgstr "The function gettext exist"

#: /home/jonathan/www/testGettext/index.php:26
msgid "La función gettext no existe"
msgstr "The function gettext doesn't exists"

#: /home/jonathan/www/testGettext/index.php:31
msgid "Hola mundo"
msgstr "Hello word!"
```

También he comprobado:

- Que tenga instalado el Gettext en el sistema de destino de la aplicación.
- Tengo activado el módulo gettext en el PHP (`phpinfo()` muestra que tengo habilitado el módulo).
- Tengo instalados los "locales".

Los que tengo instalados y habilitados:

```
# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_GB.utf8
en_US.utf8
es_ES.utf8
it_IT.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
```

Para comprobar que funciona uso las siguientes URL para modificar el idioma:

- 192.168.1.15/index.php?language=es_ES
- 192.168.1.15/index.php?language=en_GB

El resultado que obtengo:

```
La función gettext existe
en_GB
Hola mundo
```

y

```
La función gettext existe
es_ES
Hola mundo
```

En ningún caso me realiza las traducciones. Lo que me extraña mucho es que exactamente lo mismo me funciona en local, en mi servidor de desarrollo Apache. **¿Cómo puedo averiguar el error? ¿Alguien me puede indicar qué diferencia hay en la configuración del servidor Apache y Nginx en el tema de traducciones?**

Se que la solución rápida sería usar Apache en la máquina de destino, pero es un sistema embebido y es un requisito usar el servidor Nginx.

Desde ya muchísimas gracias por vuestras aportaciones.

Comment: Primero de nada, yo probaría si la extensión está cargada en nginx con un phpinfo(). Luego, según el resultado...

Comment: @track3r como menciono en el mensaje anterior ya lo he comprobado con el phpinfo(). Está habilitado.

Comment: Cierto, no lo vi, pero entonces ni idea del problema. Sorry.